# Deriving Bernoulli's equation from Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation, navier-stokes

I can prove the Bernoulli equation in an elementary way (that is, using the conservation of energy law). But I was asked to derive the Bernoulli equation from the Navier-Stokes equations, and I have no idea how to proceed. I tried searching on the Internet, but I found no good explanations.

> I was told that Bernoulli equation is $${v^{2} \over 2}+gh+{p \over \varrho }={\mathrm {const}}$$ and in class we had this form of Navier Stokes:       $$-\nabla p+\varrho \boldsymbol{b}=\varrho\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+v\nabla v\right).$$

If someone could show me how to derive Bernoulli equation from Navier-Stokes, it would be great.

Comment: Welcome on Physics SE :) It would be very helpful I think if you could add the explicit forms of the Navier Stokes and Bernoulli equations you are using to make sure that the answers are really helpful to you :)

Comment: I was told that Bernoulli equation is ${v^{2} \over 2}+gh+{p \over \varrho }={\mathrm  {const}}$, and in class we had this form of Navier Stokes:  $-\nabla p+\varrho \boldsymbol{b}=\varrho\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+v\nabla v\right)$

Comment: In the second equation you mean $-\nabla p+\varrho \boldsymbol{g}=\varrho\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}+v\nabla v\right) $? These are the Euler equations, and the derivation you seek is in Landau, Lifshitz vol 6 "Fluid Mechanics", pages 9-10. It's quite straigthforward. Otherwise, what's $\ \boldsymbol{b}$?

Comment: In the version of the Euler equation that the OP wrote down, **b** is the general body force per unit mass.  It doesn't necessarily have to be **g**.

Comment: To get the Bernoulli equation from the Euler equation, the standard method is to dot the Euler equation with the velocity **v** and to then integrate with respect to t.  This allows you to integrate along a streamline.  Incidentally, those v's in the Euler equation should be vectors.  See Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Transport Phenomena.